# Windows file in use needs to be replaced on network share

Tags: c++, vb.net, windows, user-interface, permissions

Here is my issue in as much detail as I can think:
I work on a system that contains two parts, a GUI and Calculation engine. The GUI is programmed in VB.net, and the engine in C++. Both are delivered by moving their exe files to a network folder, where the users of the system have a shortcut installed don their machine to open the exe. The GUI calls the calc engine to pass its input and everything works great.

When issues arise or changes are needed, I make the required changes and copy the exe files and past over them. The calculation engine has no problem being overwritten and the changes take immediate effect. The GUI is a different story, hence my question:

How do I overwrite the GUI.exe on the network folder when it is in use? There are many people using the exe and I constantly get "file in use, try again/cancel" messages. Is there a way to overwrite this file, even if that has negative consequences for the users until they restart it? As of right now, I need to get everyone to shut the program on their machine down, and once I am notified that everyone is out of the system, I can change it. This takes a long time and I am looking or a better solution. For example, if someone leaves the system on overnight and goes on vacation, its locked until they shut it down or their machine.

The exe is manually copied from my local machine and pasted to this network folder. Thanks in advance for any insight and suggestions/solutions.

Comment: If you aren't looking for a "proper/official" way. I usually just rename the old file and copy the new one. When the old file isn't in use, I delete it.

Comment: I run into the same issue. I can't rename, delete, or replace the files while it is in use. I am looking for a way around this to deliver the system without the restraint of having all the users close the system down.

Comment: If you can't rename then you'll have to find a different strategy. You will need something that the user execute before they run the program. (ex: a short cut). That shortcut would point to the new version of the software (ex: a different folder). Or change the process, like asking user to close the program on a specific date.

Comment: The shortcut would require the user to change the path of the shortcut on their machines. This isn't ideal as the users are for the most part unskilled or do not have knowledge and would require some training. Is there a built in feature of visual studio or anything that can push code builds without the restriction of the exe being in use?